# maven - resolve compiltetime dependency to glassfish system libraries

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish, dependency-management

I've created a small EJB project in eclipse with glassfish 4. I followed this tutotial:
http://programming.manessinger.com/tutorials/an-eclipse-glassfish-java-ee-6-tutorial/

In this project I have dependencies to "glassfish system libraries" (stuff like javax.ws.rs-api or javax.annotation-api)

Now I converted my project to maven and I'm stuck on how to resolve this dependencies with maven. (Those system libraries are - a lot...) Currently my EJBs have compile errors in Eclipse because @EJB is unknown, or @Stateless.

**How do I solve this dependecy?**

Btw: JPA Annotations work/are recognized because I added this dependecy to my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@esej was absolutely correct. To solve the problem just add the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Notice: scope compile, because on the server the Java EE API is provided.